# Converting an infix expression to postfix

Tags: stacks

So the question is to convert the following expression to postfix:

```
(a+b)^(p+q)^(r*s*t)
```

The answer I get when I calculate is: `ab+pq+^rs*t*^`

**But** the answer is given to be `ab+pq+rs*t*^^`

I assume that the step when you need to push second '^' into stack when there is already a '^' in the stack is where I went wrong (I pop out the '^' before pushing). Shouldn't we pop out the first '^' as they are of equal precedence ? Or is it an exception to '^' operator ?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! The critical information is what is your "^" operator. Does it mean bit-xor or raising to a power? It would be nice to provide a url or reference to tell us the context.

Comment: Thanks! It is an exponent operator. And regarding the reference, it was a question in a small online quiz related to stacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sort of an exception to '^', the exponentiation operator since it is [**right associative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity). That is, $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{\left({b^c}\right)}$ instead of $\left(a^b\right)^c$. That is, `(a+b)^(p+q)^(r*s*t)` means `(a+b)^((p+q)^(r*s*t))` instead of `((a+b)^(p+q))^(r*s*t)`.

When you reach the first `^` while evaluating postfix expression `ab+pq+rs*t*^^`, you will pop out the result of `rs*t*` and the result of `pq+`. You get the expected exponentiation as expected.

Comment: The use of extra brackets made it all clear. Thanks a lot !

Comment: You are welcome! Please consider accepting my answer. (Thanks in word without upvote or acceptance is more like the antithesis of thanks on StackExchange.)

Comment: I actually upvoted (since I have less than 15 reputation, it doesn't show up)

Comment: I see. I just upvoted this nice question of yours so that you are nearer to the privilege of upvoting.